# django for loop optimize

Tags: python, django

I have a loop in my html that looks like this:

```
<table>
{% for behaviors in behavior %}
  <tr>
    <th>{{name.Behavior}}</th>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% for names in name %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{names.Name}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

the result in my html looks like this:

```
Aggressive
Assertive
Passive
Passive-Aggressive
...
```

So, how can I loop through it to look like this instead:

```
Name  | Aggressive | Assertive | Passive | Passive-Aggressive | ...
Mirly |            |           |         |                    |
Marta |            |           |         |                    |
```

This is my models.py:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    Name=  models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    Behavior = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to look like this:

```
Name  | Aggressive | Assertive | Passive | Passive-Aggressive | ...
Mirly |            |           |         |                    |
Marta |            |           |         |                    |
```

Change your loop to this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    {% for behaviors in behavior %}
      <th>{{behaviors}}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% for names in name %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{names}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```